# error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I get this error when launching the app in an emulator. What the app does basically is get random two numbers and outputs them into textviews. The user then puts in answer to the equation and presses the button. The app then crashes. The error I get is error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH). This shows up before the app launches, however it only terminates the app on button press.

```
public class levelone extends Activity {
private EditText numberEditText;
public int answer;
private int answerUser;
Context context;
private TextView answerText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_levelone);
    answerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);
    Random rand = new Random();
    Random rand1 = new Random();
    int number = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
    int numbers1 = rand1.nextInt(10) + 1;
    TextView number1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number1);
    TextView number2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number2);
    String String1 = String.valueOf(number);
    String String2 = String.valueOf(numbers1);
    number1.setText(String1);
    number2.setText(String2);
    answer = number + numbers1;
 Button answerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerButton);
     answerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            numberEditText.getText().toString();

            answerUser = Integer.parseInt(numberEditText.getText().toString());
            try {
                answerUser = Integer.parseInt(numberEditText.getText().toString());
            }

            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                answerUser = 0;
            }


        }

    });
```

Comment: can you add the exception stacktrace? thanks

Comment: ok I found my error, the app couldnt access a value from null object, so I needed to add the editText which was         numberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberEditText);